# Program crashes when given high values

Tags: java, int, double, java.util.scanner, system

My coding, im trying to make a program that wont crash whatever the input is from user, the program will divide and print out the answer. i have searched but could not find any help!
The coding works fine for numbers smaller than 100000000 or 199999999 you get the point.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
double n1 = in.nextInt();
double n2 = in.nextInt();
double n3 = n1/n2;
System.out.println(n3);
```

Comment: Use `double` everywhere instead of `int`?  An int in Java is 32 bits, with an upper limit of around 2 billion.

Comment: Program crashes? what does it mean, didn't you get any output or error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner for long integer, Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19698025/scanner-for-long-integer-exception-in-thread-main-java-util-inputmismatchexce)

Comment: Exactly how big of a number do you need to support?

Answer (score 2):

You are using `in.nextInt()` which will read an integer whose value less than `2^31 -1`  (of course it gets converted to `double`). But when you give values more than `(2^31) - 1` like `12589691475`, `nextInt()` can not read them as they are very big numbers.

Use `in.nextDouble()` instead.

Comment: I don't know whether it matters to the OP, but double division does behave differently from integer division.  If it can fit in a `long` that might be the first option.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
in.nextDouble();
```

or

```
in.nextLong();
```

Answer (score 0):

For arbitrary big numbers, use `java.math.BigInteger` or `java.math.BigDecimal`.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
BigInteger n1 = new BigInteger(in.nextLine());
BigInteger n2 = new BigInteger(in.nextLine());
BigInteger n3 = n1.divide(n2);
System.out.println(n3);
```