# How can give my program a long series of numbers like 123123123123?

Tags: java

Hello I am fairly new to java and I have a problem with entering long numbers

So my code is

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test {
public static void main(String []args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter int: ");
    int a = scan.nextInt();
   }
}
```

and my output is

```
Enter int: 
12312312312
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: "12312312312"
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at Test.main(Test.java:6)
```

can you help me with this problem

Comment: Hint: What's the largest possible value you can store in an int?

Comment: Looks like your taking an input longer than the primitive ```int``` can hold and ```nextInt()``` can only take an integer. Change the type to a ```long``` and it should work fine.

Comment: Nice hint Voo! This is a fairly simple problem, you should consider the maximum value for an `int` and then choose another type for your variable. Check this out: [max int](http://ice-web.cc.gatech.edu/ce21/1/static/JavaReview-RU/VariableBasics/minAndMax.html)

Comment: Also, this SO answer contains more details: [max value of integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15005226/5048820)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scanner for long integer, Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19698025/scanner-for-long-integer-exception-in-thread-main-java-util-inputmismatchexce)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use long data type instead of int.

```
long a = scan.nextLong();
```

For more info, refer https://www.javatpoint.com/java-data-types

Answer (score 0):

The reason you getting this exception it because the number you enterred is begger than the size int can represent :
[max value of integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004944/max-value-of-integer)

the reason long can work for you is becauese it have bigger size in memoery to represent higer number.

try to read more about variable types and max values

Answer (score 0):

The maximum value for an int is `2147483647` and you have `12312312312`. Try a `long` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can read it as a string and convert it to a big integer since it has "[no limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088436/what-does-biginteger-having-no-limit-mean)".

```
BigInteger a = new BigInteger(scan.nextString());
```

Comment: Np :). If this answer is of any use can you upvote and accept so that I can actually use SO?

Answer (score 0):

The value `12312312312` is too large to fit into an `int`.

Many people suggest to switch to `long` in order to fix your problem. That indeed fixes this specific problem, but if your values are much larger, than even `long` may be insufficient.

If you want to be able to input very large values, then you may want to switch to `BigInteger`. It can hold an arbitrary large number, and your only upper limit is your computer's memory.

The `Scanner` class even has methods for it:

```
int a = scan.nextBigInteger();
```